# Python subpackage import "no module named x"

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package

I'm trying to build a package that has the following structure,

- __init__.py
- a.py
- subpackage

  - __init__.py
  - b.py

a.py file contains a class from b.py, let say "classX".
So, a.py has the following line at the beginning of file,

```
from subpackage.b import classX
```

The problem is that, when I try to use this entire package from outside, I get the error "no module named 'b'".

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: "when I try to use this entire package from outside", from a.py?

Comment: @RishabhKumar from an outside python file, in an upper directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directory structure should be

```
package (choose whatever name you want for the high-level package name)
    __init__.py
    a.py
    subpackage
        __init__.py
        b.py
```

The *parent* directory of `package` needs to be in the `sys.path` list of directories to be searched for resolving imports. This can be accomplished by having that directory being the current working directory when you invoke whatever program you are running or adding the directory to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or modifying `sys.path` at runtime before doing your imports.

Then `a.py` should be either:

```py
from package.subpackage.b import classX
```

or

```py
from .subpackage.b import classX
```